# php string manipulation issues

Tags: php, explode, substr

I have the following string...

```
$string = "True is True (5-7 years)";
```

what I want is to get - TiT(5-7 years)

I have tried the following code but no luck...

```
$string = "True is True (5-7 years)"; 
$explodedString = explode(" ",$string); 
for($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++){ 
    $tempString = substr($explodedString[$i], 0, 1); 
    $finalString .= $tempString; 
}
```

In short, I need the first three words of its initials and the remaining in bracket is as it is like this.... TiT(5-7 years). how?

Comment: You might want to include more details about what other inputs might be.  Your output could be achieved in many ways.

Comment: what i want is the output only. show me if you have any way how do i achieve the above output as it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This a good case for using regular expressions:

```
$str = 'True is True (5-7 years)';
preg_match_all('~\([^()]*\)|\b\w~', $str, $matches);
echo implode("", $matches[0]); // TiT(5-7 years)
```

Regex breakdown:

- `\([^()]*\)` Match anything inside parentheses including themselves
- `|` Or
- `\b\w` Match first word character from a word

Comment: Thanks for every one I just given 1, But the perfect answer for me is Mr.Revo. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

Your loop is going one element too far. If you want the first letter of the first 3 words, it should be `$i < 3`.

Then you should use `array_slice()` and `implode()` to concatenate the rest of the array.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
    $finalString .= $explodedString[$i][0];
}
$finalString .= implode(' ', array_slice($explodedString, 3));
```

[DEMO](https://ideone.com/MX53lM)

Comment: is that possible we could make the 3 by n? if the string is less or more??

Comment: Sure, but that's not what you asked.

Answer (score 1):

```
$string = "True is True (5-7 years)"; 
$new_string = preg_replace('/^([a-z])[a-z]+ ([a-z])[a-z]+ ([a-z])[a-z]+ (\(.+\))$/i', '$1$2$3$4', $string);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all.
Create an empty variable. That will be your final result

```
$result="";
```

Then youse foreach to loop your explode string.
At every part chech the first character. 
If it's not (  add the first char onto the result variable.
else add the whole array element onto the result variable

```
foreach(explodedString as $t){
If($t[0] !="("){$result.=$t[0];} else{$result.=$t;}
}
```

At the end of the loop you will get what you wanted

```
echo $result;
```